# Angular ReferenceError: response is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am new at Angular and I'm doing some tests and get stuck in this tutorial where it says: 
angular.min.js:116 ReferenceError: response is not at onUserComplete

```
    var app = angular.module('example', []);
    var mainController = function($scope, $http){

        var onUserComplete = function($scope){
            $scope.user = response.data;
        }

        var onError= function(reason){
            $scope.error = "Could not fetch data";
        }

        $scope.search = function(username){
            $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/"+username)
            .then(onUserComplete, onError);
            $scope.username = "angular";
            $scope.message = "Hello World"
        }
    }
    app.controller('mainController', mainController);
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: change `var onUserComplete = function($scope)` to `var onUserComplete = function(response)`

Answer (score 1):

Here there is no meaning of sending your $scope as parameter in the function, try to avoid doing this even after the tutorial

I think the tutorial wants you to change `$scope` to `response` in here

```
var onUserComplete = function(response){
    $scope.user = response.data;
}
```

Here you are assigning the data of your response to the `scope.user` where you can use it anywhere the `$scope` can gp

Answer (score 0):

When you take a closer look, your function `onUserComplete()` is working with a `response` variable but didn't received this variable anyhow. You need to pass it in.

As Daniel proposed, the correction is to change the function argument to `response` (this is what the function will receive from the `$http` object.

```js
    var app = angular.module('example', []);
    var mainController = function($scope, $http){

        var onUserComplete = function(response){
            $scope.user = response.data;
        }

        var onError= function(reason){
            $scope.error = "Could not fetch data";
        }

        $scope.search = function(username){
            $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/"+username)
            .then(onUserComplete, onError);
            $scope.username = "angular";
            $scope.message = "Hello World"
        }
    }
    app.controller('mainController', mainController);
```